# when running multiple nuxtjs programmatic api instances is there caching?

Tags: nuxt.js

Take the below example on a fresh instance of nuxt using `npx create-nuxt-app`

**Expectation**
The second build to only generate a client version

**Result**
The second build generates both client and server version

```
import { Nuxt, Builder, Generator } from "nuxt";

(async () => {
  // build server and client version
  const nuxt = new Nuxt({
    dev: false,
    mode: "universal"
  });
  await nuxt.ready();
  await new Builder(nuxt).build();

  // build client version only
  const nuxt2 = new Nuxt({
    dev: false,
    mode: "spa"
  });
  await nuxt2.ready();
  await new Builder(nuxt2).build();
})();
```

It seems as though some part of nuxt is being cached or brought over from the first instance.

Is it possible to achieve what I want (no server build) on the second build?

*PS: I am currently able to achieve what I want using [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) in node, however this is not ideal.*